# Radeon Xpress 200M with Hardware Acceleration on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kernel, laptop, radeon, fglrx

my notebook is running with the ATI Radeon Xpress 200M, which isn't supported by AMD anymore on Linux >2.6.28(fglrx 9.3). I would like to enable hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

xpress200 is no more supported by actual xserver, so try with an older one from natty for example

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Comment: According to that second link "Radeon XPRESS 200(M)/1100 IGP" is supported.